# HtmlHelper and Html after definition of extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to C#. I cannot understand the following code ( I am presenting a part of it):

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString DisplayTest(this HtmlHelper helper, string code)
     {
        ...
        texthtmlhelper = string.Format("<span>" + ... + "</span>");
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(texthtmlhelper);
     }
}
```

As to access the above method:

```
<div>
    @Html.DisplayTest("ck")
</div>
```

`DisplayTest` becomes an *extension method* of `HtmlHelper`. How can we access it through `Html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @Html is an object of HtmlHelper class

so you can access HtmlHelper extention method using `@Html`

Answer (score 0):

`DisplayText` is an extension method for `HtmlHelper`. Please find more details about extension method [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

That method will create a span to display the given text. The below code will call the extension method `DisplayText`

```
<div>
    @Html.DisplayTest("ck")
</div>
```

Hope this clarifies you.